# Slick2D Rectangle Collision Detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, intersection, slick2d, rectangles

I'm having an issue showing that one rectangle has collided with another. So my question is, how can I get the intersect method to check for collision? Or are there any other ways to handle collision in this situation?

I'm creating a turn-based combat game (similar to Final Fantasy or Legend of Dragoon) where the player's character is on the right side of the screen and the enemy is on the left side. The player and enemy each take turns attacking. So when the player attacks, the sprite animation moves across the screen from right to left until it stops in front of the enemy, attacks, and returns to it's starting coordinates. Both the player and enemy have a rectangle drawn around them to represent the bounds of each character.

When the player moves forward, he passes through the Enemy's rectangle and stops within it. At this point there should be output to the console saying "INTERSECT!" to show that there was a collision between the two rectangles, but unfortunately there isn't.

Please note that I have omitted the unnecessary pieces of code within my classes and tried to provide the code that pertains to my problem.

This is my entry point, GameClass:

```
public class GameClass extends BasicGame{
//other variable declarations

public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
player = new Player();
enemy = new Enemy();
skeleton = new Skeleton();
enemy = skeleton;
playX = player.getStartX(); //700
playY = player.getStartY(); //140
playW = player.rect.getWidth(); //40
playH = player.rect.getHeight(); //70
enemyX = enemy.getStartX(); //100
enemyY = enemy.getStartY(); //140
enemyWidth = enemy.getWidth(); //50
enemyHeight = enemy.getHeight(); //55

SpriteSheet sheet = new SpriteSheet("data/homeranim.png", 36, 65);
    anim = new Animation();
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        anim.addFrame(sheet.getSprite(i,0), 150);
    }
}

public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {
anim.draw(playX,playY); // draws player animation
skeletonAnim.draw(enemyX, enemyY); // draws enemy
g.draw(player.rect); //draws player bounds
g.draw(enemy.rect); //draws enemy bounds
}

public void update(GameContainer container, int delta)
        throws SlickException {
playerUpdate(delta);
if (player.rect.intersects(enemy.rect)) {
             System.out.println("INTERSECT!");

         System.out.println("Player minX: " + player.rect.getMinX());
         System.out.println("Player maxX: " + player.rect.getMaxX());
         System.out.println("Enemy minX: " + enemy.rect.getMinX());
         System.out.println("Enemy maxX: " + enemy.rect.getMaxX());
         }
      }

public void playerUpdate(int delta) {
    if (playerForward == true){
       playX -= delta * 0.4f;
       if (playX <= 140) {
             playX = 140;
             playerForward = false;
             playerBackward = true;}
  }

   if (playerBackward == true) {
         playX += delta * 0.4f;
         if (playX >= 700) {
             playX = 700;
             playerBackward = false;
             delay = 1250;
  }

public void keyReleased(int key, char c) {
       if (key == Input.KEY_ENTER){
          playerForward = true;}
}
}
```

This is a glimpse at my Player class:

```
public class Player {

private int startX = 700;
private int startY = 140;
public Shape rect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, 40, 70);
//plus getters and setters
}
```

And my entire Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy {

private int startX, startY, width, height;
public Shape rect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, width, height);
// plus getters and setters
   }
```

My Skeleton class extends Enemy:

```
public class Skeleton extends Enemy {

public Skeleton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setMaxHealth(120);
    setStartX(100);
    setStartY(140);
    setWidth(50);
    setHeight(55);
}

}
```

Note: Since I've switched g.drawRect() to g.draw(), enemy rectangle isn't being drawn.

Rect bounds at starting point: http://i.imgur.com/QDDk858.png

Rect bound where collision should be: http://i.imgur.com/pOANfvN.png

I hope I've provided enough code to show you what my problem is. I've rummaged through the internet for hours with no luck. If there is any other code I need to provide, please do not hesitate to ask. Thank you very much for your help and support!

Comment: So what is your exact problem? The intersects method isnt being triggered?

Comment: And why are your creating the hitboxes with centerX and centerY instead of x and y. The arguments for Rectangle constructor are (startX, startY, width, height), not the center. So this might be your problem, as then the hitboxes will be offset.

Comment: Precisely, the intersects method isn't being triggered. The variables centerX and centerY were just poorly named because the rectangles are not drawn offset or anything, woops! They represent startX and startY. EDIT: I have changed centerX to startX, etc.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the rectangles (making them visibile, Graphics.draw(Shape shape))?

Comment: Oh are you updating the hitbox positions? The rectangles need to be repositioned, I assume you are just changing the playX, playY, enemyX, etc.. values, not the rectangles (hitboxes) themselves?

Comment: The rectangles are already visible with g.drawRect(), but I just tried using g.draw() now. The rectangles are no longer visible, but now for some reason my console keeps spamming "INTERSECT!" output even before the characters move anywhere.

Comment: When I change the playX value of the character, the x values of the hitbox change with it so they both end up moving together.

Comment: Well it seems like there is something wrong with your hitbox positions. Mind sharing a screenshot of the hitbox positions / and upload the complete (well, the code responsible for hitbox moving, moving in general and updating the hitboxes and such) code somehwere and share it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the hitbox positions themselves.

You are drawing this:

```
g.drawRect(playX, playY, playW, playH); //draws player bounds
g.drawRect(enemyX, enemyY, enemyW, enemyH); //draws enemy bounds
```

But this isn't the actual hitbox, it's just the position of the player/enemy and the rectangles drawn here will be on the correct position while the hitboxes themselves aren't.

I suggest you do the following:

```
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta)
{
    playerUpdate(delta);

    player.rect.setLocation(playX, playY);
    enemy.rect.setLocation(enemyX, enemyY); // update the hitboxes to the new positions

    if (player.rect.intersects(enemy.rect))
    {
        System.out.println("INTERSECT!");
    }
}

public void playerUpdate(int delta)
{
    if (playerForward == true)
    {
       playX -= delta * 0.4f;

       if (playX <= 140) 
       {
             playX = 140;
             playerForward = false;
             playerBackward = true;
       }
    }

    if (playerBackward == true) 
    {
         playX += delta * 0.4f;

         if (playX >= 700) 
         {
             playX = 700;
             playerBackward = false;
             delay = 1250;
         }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(int key, char c) 
{
   if (key == Input.KEY_ENTER)
   {
      playerForward = true;
   }
}
```

Furthermore, as you seem to be new to game development in Java, some tips for you:

- **Format your code properly**

Always place full {...} after if, else, switch, while, for, etc.; proper line indentation, .

- **Think OO (Object-Oriented)**

This one is pretty important. Your enemy and player class should both extend some kind of entity class because they both will pretty much want to obtain similar behavior (avoid code duplication!). Sum up similar behavior to a super class, simplify the behavior to be controlled with a few adjustable parameters and so on.

For example, you store the positions of your enemy and player as a static integer in your main class. This is not OO. Move the positions to the entity class where you can implement it in whatever manner you wish.

- **Don't just throw an exception for no reason**

Your update(...) method throws a SlickException even though it's never needed.

- **Be careful about encapsulation**

This is something a lot of beginners do: Just grab some parameters, put them in a class as private (or maybe even public) and generate getters- and setters for them. This is **not** encapsulation. This is almost as bad as making them public in the first place.

But why don't we just make everything public?

We don't want anyone (or even ourselves) to rely on some parameters that just happen to be there because of some very specific implementation of something we might want to change later. Don't just put all possible values out there to be changed, the sense of encapsulation is to be independent from what kind of implementation we end up using and to protect the usability of our code by guarding what can be set/changed.

- **Performance does matter**

This is one of the aspects you should watch out for, for any kind of software, but you can often most drastically see the consequences in games. Performance is important! And by that, I don't mean that you have to watch out for every single detail, but just keep an overview in mind on how to improve and fasten up your code, especially with frequently called methods such as update(..) and render(..) in Slick2D.

**Update**

As a solution to another problem discussed in the comments:

```
public class Enemy {

    private int startX, startY, width, height;
    public Shape rect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, width, height);
    // plus getters and setters
}
```

width and height can only be 0 as they are never assigned an integers have the value 0 per default, so the enemy rectangle hitbox does have 0 width and will never trigger.

Try something like:

```
 public class Enemy {

    private int startX, startY, width = 50, height = 70;
    public Shape rect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, width, height);
    // plus getters and setters
 }
```

This should work, but you should probably move all these attributes to the enemy class and put them in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to Java game development! Thank you very much for the helpful tips, an Entity superclass would be a much better idea for what I'm trying to do.
I've tried replacing g.drawRect() with g.draw(player.rect) and I've added the two setLocation() lines you recommended. Unfortunately, the intersects method isn't being triggered. I will continue to make adjustments based on your suggestions.

Comment: @RookieCookie Hmm... this is really weird. Usually, the intersects method works without any trouble. Have you tried to look if the bounds of the rectangles actually update properly? Just print the player.rect.getMinX(), player.rect.getMaxX()... and so on and post what it says.

Comment: I agree, I had hoped the intersects method wouldn't give me such a headache! I have included the output lines you've suggested and updated photos. Please tell me if this is what you were referring to in your last comment.Currently I can only post 2 links (not enough rep points).

Comment: @RookieCookie Um what do you mean by "enemy rectangle not being drawn"? Doesn't this mean that the enemy hitbox is in the wrong place and thats probably why intersects(..) doesn't trigger?

Comment: I think I got it! In my Enemy class I create the rectangle, and parameters 'width' and 'height' are outputting values of '0'. But if I replace width and height with hardcoded values in the Enemy class (not as efficient, I know), it works! So I just need to get to the bottom of that and it's fixed! It's weird though, I set width, height, x, and y in the Skeleton class but only width and height are returning 0.

Comment: Success! The intersects method is being triggered now. I thought I was setting width for Enemy within the Skeleton class, but I guess not!  Thanks again for your help, it's immensely appreciated.